# Can't convert a variable to an integer (because of an if statement?)

Tags: python

Sorry for asking, but I'm writing a program for a past paper question to find if a user entered number is prime, then looping it.

The issue is that I can't seem to convert the input `userno` from a `float` to an `int` in the if statement.

Any help would be much appreciated

```py
run = True

while run == True:

    userno = float(input("Please enter a number to check if it's a prime number."))

    if userno < 1:
        print ("The number entered was lower than 1, so can't be prime.")
    else:
        int(userno)                         #this doesn't seem to work
        for norange in range (2,userno):    #userno is still a float here
            if userno % norange == 0:
                print ("This is not a prime number, sorry.")
            else:
                print ("This is a prime number. :)")

    runagain = input ("Do you want to enter another number? Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
    if runagain == "no":
        run = False
```

Comment: You meant `userno = int(userno)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(userno)` returns userno as an integer but it does not overwrite the `userno` actual variable's value.

You need to use `userno = int(userno)`